What were the attributes of ' a god' that Moses was 'made' in Exodus 6&7?
We read in Ex 6:28-30 and 7:1(KJV):

And it came to pass on the day when the Lord spake unto Moses in the land of Egypt.
That the Lord spake unto Moses, saying, I am the Lord: speak thou unto Pharaoh king of Egypt all that I say unto thee.And Moses said before the Lord, Behold, I am of uncircumcised lips, and how shall Pharaoh hearken unto me?And the Lord said unto Moses, See, I have made thee a god to Pharaoh: and Aaron thy brother shall be thy prophet.

Note that the word ' ..god' does not start with capital 'G' and is preceded by the article ' a' . But such grammatical constraints are not applicable to all languages. Is it that the word God would later attain a definitive meaning with the Commandments ? My question is : What were the attributes of ' a god' that Moses was 'made' in Exodus 6&7 ?

First, the Hebrew does not have an indefinite article equivalent to the English "a".
Second, the literal wording of Ex 7:1 is:

So, Yahweh said to Moses, "See, I have made you god to Pharoah; Aaron
your brother shall be your prophet.

Thus, most versions translate this as:

"like God" NIV, NLT, ESV, BSB, CSB, HCSB, etc
"as God", NKJV, NASB, LSB, ASV, etc

The Pulpit commentary explains this well:

I have made thee a god to Pharaoh. Moses was diffident of appearing a second time before Pharaoh, who was so much his worldly
superior. God reminds him that he is in truth very much Pharaoh's
superior. If Pharaoh has earthly, he has unearthly power. He is to
Pharaoh "as a god," with a right to command his obedience, and with
strength to enforce his commands.

